# Looping over two dataframes

Tags: r, function, loops

I have the following code lines and I want to do the text analysis for both male and female words using the fommands below

```
words_male <- subset(Dec_10_Spreadsheet, Gender=="Male")
words_female<- subset(Dec_10_Spreadsheet, Gender="Female")

words_female<- words_female %>% 
  select(Text) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word,Text) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words) %>%
  filter(word != "meeting", word != "speaking", word != "government", word != "house", word!= "question", words!="issue", word!="policy",word!="speaker")



words_female %>% 
  count(word,sort=T) %>% 
  slice(1:20) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(word, n, function(n) -n), y = n)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) + 
  xlab("")

words_male<- words_male %>% 
  select(Text) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word,Text) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words) 


words_male %>% 
  count(word,sort=T) %>% 
  slice(1:20) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(word, n, function(n) -n), y = n)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) + 
  xlab("")
```

I want to optimize this code so that it loops over the male and female datasets without having to repeat the lines twice. I might have to segment this data further as well into many different subsets so having a code like this will be very helpful. Any ideas? I will gift you a starbucks coffee :)

Comment: Write a function with `words_male` or `words_female` as input/argument doing the things shown above.

Comment: this worked: list<- c("words_male", "words_female")
myplot<- function(data, title){
  data%>%
  count(word,sort=T) %>% 
    slice(1:20) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = reorder(word, n, function(n) -n), y = n)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) + 
    xlab(title)
}

for (i in list){
  print(myplot(get(i), i))
}

Comment: You can actually answer your own question. ;-)